# Sending Ajax request to controller implicitly in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have form with a lot of inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="SomeName1" name="SomeName1" />
<input type="text" id="SomeName2" name="SomeName2" />
etc...
```

All these inputs are part of my viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SomeName1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeName2 { get; set; }
    //etc...
}
```

I need to refresh all those inputs without refreshing whole page, so I need to use Ajax request. However the problem is that we need explicitly define viewmodel in Javascript and send it via `jquery.ajax`, like this:

```
var viewModel = 
{
    SomeName1: $("#SomeName1").val(),
    //etc...
}
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateAction", "SomeController")',
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: viewModel,
    datatype: "json"
})
request.done(function (data) {
    $("#SomeName1").val(data.SomeName1);
    //etc...                                   
})
```

So, there is a lot of copy-paste code, which is hard to edit and support.

I don't want explicitly send data, like in example, from all inputs and then explicitly set new data to all that inputs.

What should I do with this?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Can you explain what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: what do you want to do ? tell it in detail please

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan edited question, added example.

Comment: while sending use $("your form selector").serialize() in ajax data it gets input values with their names.

Comment: @mayk this solves problem with sending, but what should we do with refreshing after answer?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **mayk's** answer, which give me idea how can I solve it, I've written simple solution:

```
var viewModel = $("#myFormId").serializeObject();
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateAction", "SomeController")',
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: viewModel,
    datatype: "json"
})
request.done(function (data) {
       $.each(data, function (key, value) {
           $("#myFormId) input[name=" + key + "]").val(value);
       });                               
})
```

Where:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

serialize your form to

```
var viewModel = 
{
    SomeName1: $("#SomeName1").val(),
    //etc...
}
```

Javascript object, then send viewmodel to your controller, which returns this viewmodel again. Returned viewmodel simply applies to each input in form with corresponding names.