# Form reset function returned undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I am trying to reset form inputs by :

```
$("#form_employee_job")[0].reset();
```

The inputs still filled and console return `undefined`

What i'm missing ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'the console returns `undefined`'? `reset()` doesn't return anything, so I'm not sure what exactly you're expecting to happen here

Comment: I mean the browser console, cos i tried this code at browser console, i expect that form inputs will be reset, but nothing happened

Comment: In which case we need to see the HTML of your form, as what you have works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/eq67q7bz/ Please edit your question to include it

Comment: Everything must be ok if "form_employee_job" is id of your form tag.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Here is the form code, it's about 360 line of code

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yn2xeq6z/1/

If your form id is`form_employee_job` then everything should work as expected. All input field of Form will be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're missing something else, outside of the code you've posted here?

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2873/) that might help you on your way. This example will reset the form when you press the button.

HTML

```
<form id='form_employee_job'>
  <input type='text'/>
</form>
<button id="btn">reset</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#form_employee_job")[0].reset();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your form might have POST data in the fields with the POST/GET request. In this case, form reset will not work.

I am not 100% sure if this is bug or the way it works.

If you have programmatically assined some values to the input, it might be able to not reset.

In order to achieve reset, you can empty the form inputs.

```
$(':input','#myform')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');
```

Please see this post [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery)