# Programm edit entity instead add

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

There is modal window in my jsp. I use it for both: add or edit my items. It decides what to do depends on "id": add if "id" is null, edit - if not null.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="editRow">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="detailsForm">
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">

                    ...

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="save()">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                               </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Generally it works fine, but there is one scenario which does not work:

1. I open "edit" windows for some item
2. Don't save it, just close "edit" window
3. Open "add" window, enter some data
4. After saving it edit item from 1), instead adding new one

There is button on this jsp, which I press to call "add" window:

```
        <a class="btn btn-info" onclick="add('<spring:message code="meals.add"/>')">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
```

There is "add" js function from this button:

```
var form;
...
form = $('#detailsForm');
...
    function add(title) {
        $('#modalTitle').html(title);
        form[0].reset();
        $('#editRow').modal();
    }
```

I thought `form[0].reset();` should prevent such wrong scenario, but seems it does not help. Could you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that reset() doesn't nullify your form's id, instead it will clear form's input.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

Comment: Yes, and other <input> tags are really cleared. So, as id is in <input> tag, I expected it also will be cleared.

Comment: Again, reset clears user's input. I agree that it's not clear; I think you could find your answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery