# Why my post-form is not reseting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could you help me with my post-form? I am gonna try realised reseting form after closing modal window with message about sending, but it isn't working! Why? I'm using Bootstrap 3.

```html
<form id='send-form' action="#" method="post" target="iframe1">
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail...">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Тема...">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="on" name="law">check</input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-effect" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#modal-send">send</button>

</form>

<div class="modal" id="modal-send">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button id='reset-but' class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-close fa-2x"></i></button>
                <script>
                    $(index.html).ready(function(){
                    $('#reset-but').click(function () {
                    $('#send-form')[0].reset();
                    });});
                </script>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Сообщение отправлено<br><br></h4>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery

Comment: What's index.html here? Try $(document).ready(function(){... instead of $(index.html).ready(function(){ ....

Comment: Did it, isn't work too

Comment: @Andreykin, K K is correct here. Have a look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7rkfuLws/

Answer (score 1):

Just delete `$(index.html).ready(function(){}` and it will works

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='send-form' action="#" method="post" target="iframe1">
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail...">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Тема...">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="on" name="law">check</input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-send">send</button>

</form>

<button id='reset-but' type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
<i class="fa fa-close fa-2x"></i></button>
<script>
$('#reset-but').click(function () {
$('#send-form')[0].reset();
});
</script>
<h4 class="modal-title">Сообщение отправлено<br><br></h4>
```

Comment: Or, edit it from $(index.html) to $(document) for that matter. Tested in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7rkfuLws/

Comment: Your code is really works here, but it isn't work on my localhost..

Comment: @AndreykinSergey can you send folder with your project? telegin.zhenya@gmail.com

Comment: @ZhenyaTelegin yes, sure

Comment: @AndreykinSergey check mail ^^

Comment: @ZhenyaTelegin thank you so much!the problem was in importing jQuery lib