# Button to reset the selected option in dropdown list

Tags: php, html, reset-button

I have a page with 2 `select option dropdown lists` and I can only use one of them each time I have to submit the selected option but if I use two and click on submit i get an error **Only use one list** and thats how it should work.

for example:

I have 2 drop lists like this one
[image]
[image] 
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

if i choose both like the pic above and click on submit I get an error and the selected options are shown as the deffult option and thats what I want,
but when I click on the reset button it need to reset them to the default value but nothing happens.

like this

[image]

The Options for the dropdown list is from two different arrays.

`$test1` and `$test2` are two different arrays

```
<form name="rechner" method = "POST">
<select name="one">
    <option value="" selected hidden>Choose One</option>
           <?php foreach ($test1 as $one => $value) { ?>
           <option value="<?= $value ?>" 
           <?php if ($_POST['one'] == $value) { 
                     echo 'selected="selected"';}?> ><?= $value ?>
            </option><?php
                }
            ?>
</select> 

<select name="two">
    <option value="" selected hidden>Choose one</option>
        <?php foreach ($test2 as $two => $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $value ?>" 
        <?php if ($_POST['two'] == $value) {
                  echo 'selected="selected"';}?> ><?= $value ?>
         </option><?php
        }
        ?>
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="calc" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">

</form>

  if ($_POST['calc'] == "Berechnen") {
    /// do something
 }
```

Comment: Provide complete sample of your codes to get helps.

Comment: Or please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you expect that button to do? Any reset button should only reset the form's fields to the state in which they were loaded, and if you write some configuration to the initial markup (like you do in that `foreach` loop), you modify the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer on other question
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function resetForm($myform) {
            $myform.find('input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
            $myform.find('input:radio,input:checkbox')
                        .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected);
     }
</script>
<form name="rechner" method = "POST" id="myform">
           /////html code/////

<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetForm($('#myform'));">
</form>
```